# Where can I get a complete set of keyboard key icons?

Tags: keyboard, icons

I am looking for a complete set of icons representing the keys on the keyboard.  Preferably licensed so I can use them.

It would be awesome if each key had a corresponding 'pressed' icon.

Does anyone know where I might find one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess this is what you are searching for: [Free Keyboard Graphics and Key Icons - speedflips](https://github.com/q2apro/keyboard-keys-speedflips). Keyboard key icons as SVG and PNG graphics.

License: **Public Domain - Free for commercial and private use**

Screenshot:

[image: keyboard key icons]

Demo video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eUWKDNdg1E

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This, sir, is sick.  I'm pretty sure this didn't exist when I posted this.

Comment: It it me or is the windows key missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found:
http://www.iconarchive.com/show/keyboard-keys-icons-by-chromatix.html

You can't use them for commercial use, have to post an attribution, and there is no 'pressed' version of each key.

Comment: This ones are really beautiful, but the author does not release or provide a contact :(